# jProgressBar with Threads for Database data Insertion

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, progress-bar

I'm trying to implement a JprogressBar to show the data insertion progress.
Basically the user select how many data sources will be imported to database.
With this parameter the main program Start a method to list those parameters and with a foreach loop it calls the insertion Thread and the ProgressBar update Thread.

```
for (Maquina i : m.listar()) {
    //Passing to Import Thread the object with the data and a Date parameter
    ImportarDados imp = new ImportarDados(i, jDateInicial.getDate());

    //Calling progress bar update Thread with the progressbar itself and progress parameter
    BarraDeProgresso bp = new BarraDeProgresso(progresso, progImportacao);

    imp.run();
    bp.run();
}
```

The threads kinda work on their own, but the result is not the one I want, cause the data is being imported and the progressbar is being updated, but it is being update to 100% after all data is imported. I need to update the progress bar as long as the import thread finish the importation for each (Maquina i) object.

If it is necessary I can provide the threads code...but i don't know if this calling method can provide the result I want. Searching on the forum i found something about EDT and i think it is the problem that the bar is not being updated. Can you guys help me solving this?

Minimal and Verifiable example:
My code is pretty short. The code generated by netbeans is huge, sry for that.

That code simulate my problem. The windows is refreshed only after the for loop is finished. But the BarraDeProgresso thread is running at the same as and SysOut some info...

```
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JProgressBar;



public class Minimo extends javax.swing.JFrame {


   public Minimo() {
       initComponents();
   }

   private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
       int progImportacao[] = {0};

       progresso.setMaximum(15);
       for (int i = 0; i <= 15; i++) {
           ImportarDados imp = new ImportarDados(i,lblProgresso);
           BarraDeProgresso bp = new BarraDeProgresso(progresso, progImportacao);

           imp.run();
           bp.run();

           progImportacao[0] += 1;
       }
   }
```

Component Initialization (Netbeans Generated)

```
private void initComponents() {

    progresso = new javax.swing.JProgressBar();
    lblProgresso = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();

    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    lblProgresso.setText("...");

    jButton1.setText("IMPORT DATA");
    jButton1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            jButton1ActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
    getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGap(60, 60, 60)
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addComponent(lblProgresso)
                .addComponent(progresso, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 382, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
            .addContainerGap(47, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addComponent(jButton1)
            .addGap(191, 191, 191))
    );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGap(32, 32, 32)
            .addComponent(jButton1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 49, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, 29, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addComponent(lblProgresso)
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
            .addComponent(progresso, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addGap(37, 37, 37))
    );

    pack();
}// </editor-fold>
```

Runnable classes

```
class BarraDeProgresso implements Runnable {

    public JProgressBar jProgressBar1;
    public int progresso[];

    public BarraDeProgresso(JProgressBar barra, int progresso[]) {
        this.jProgressBar1 = barra;
        this.progresso = progresso;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(0);
            System.out.println("TBARRA PROG " + progresso[0]);
            jProgressBar1.setValue(progresso[0]);
            jProgressBar1.repaint();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        }

    }
}

class ImportarDados implements Runnable {

    private int pi = 0;
    JLabel x;

    public ImportarDados(int i, JLabel tag) {
        this.pi = i;
        this.x = tag;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(500);

            x.setText(Integer.toString(pi)+" /15");

        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Minimo.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

    }
}
```

Main (Netbeans Generated)

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
    //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
    /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
     * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
     */
    try {
        for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
            if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                break;
            }
        }
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Minimo.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Minimo.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Minimo.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Minimo.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    //</editor-fold>

    /* Create and display the form */
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new Minimo().setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") really should include the desired behavior, and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it *in the question itself*. Please create and post your [mcve] so we can play with a small compilable and runnable program and so that we can test your code ourselves, and hopefully modify it so that it will work. Note that we **do not want to see your entire program**, nor should you post a link to a code repository. Instead keep it small, keep it simple, and make it functioning. Luck.

Comment: Apparently It is now working as intended. I'm gonna learn more about it with the Lesson provided. I have been conding for like 3 months and I'm always trying to get better. Thx a lot for yout help @Hovercraft Full Of Eels . I'm gonna take a look at the code you wrote and try to optimize mine.

Comment: Thx @Bug for the help too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current code creates no background thread. Yes you've got Runnables, but you call `run()` on them, meaning you are *calling them on the Swing event thread*. When you do this, you block the event thread, effectively freezing your program. Instead, you need to:

- Create a true background thread by passing your Runnable into a Thread object's constructor and calling `start()` on that Thread.
- Not mutate Swing components from within these background threads
- Or use a SwingWorker as per the [Lesson: Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) which will help solve *both* of the above issues.

For an example of use of a SwingWorker, please see:

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.beans.PropertyChangeEvent;
import java.beans.PropertyChangeListener;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;
import javax.swing.*;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class Minimo2 extends JPanel {
    private static final int EB_GAP = 15;
    private static final int PROG_BAR_WDTH = 400;
    public static final int MAX_DATA = 15;
    private JProgressBar progresso;
    private JLabel lblProgresso;
    private JButton jButton1;
    private Action importDataAction = new ImportDataAction("Import Data");

    public Minimo2() {
        initComponents();
    }

    private void initComponents() {
        progresso = new JProgressBar(0, MAX_DATA);
        lblProgresso = new JLabel(" ");
        jButton1 = new JButton(importDataAction);
        int progBarHeight = progresso.getPreferredSize().height;
        progresso.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(PROG_BAR_WDTH, progBarHeight));
        progresso.setStringPainted(true);

        JPanel btnPanel = new JPanel();
        btnPanel.add(jButton1);
        JPanel labelPanel = new JPanel();
        labelPanel.add(lblProgresso);
        JPanel progressPanel = new JPanel();
        progressPanel.add(progresso);

        setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(EB_GAP, EB_GAP, EB_GAP, EB_GAP));
        setLayout(new BoxLayout(this, BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS));
        add(btnPanel);
        add(Box.createVerticalStrut(EB_GAP));
        add(labelPanel);
        add(Box.createVerticalStrut(EB_GAP));
        add(progressPanel);
    }

    private class ImportDataAction extends AbstractAction {
        public ImportDataAction(String name) {
            super(name); // give the button text
            int mnemonic = (int) name.charAt(0);
            putValue(MNEMONIC_KEY, mnemonic); // give it a hot key
        }

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            setEnabled(false); // disable our button
            ImportDataWorker worker = new ImportDataWorker(MAX_DATA);
            worker.addPropertyChangeListener(new WorkerListener());
            worker.execute();
        }
    }

    private class WorkerListener implements PropertyChangeListener {
        @Override
        public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent evt) {
            if ("progress".equals(evt.getPropertyName())) {
                int progValue = (int) evt.getNewValue();
                progresso.setValue(progValue);
                String text = String.format("%02d/15", progValue);
                lblProgresso.setText(text);
            } else if ("state".equals(evt.getPropertyName())) {
                if (evt.getNewValue() == SwingWorker.StateValue.DONE) {
                    @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
                    SwingWorker worker = (SwingWorker)evt.getSource();
                    try {
                        worker.get();
                    } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    progresso.setValue(MAX_DATA);
                    String text = String.format("%02d/15", MAX_DATA);
                    lblProgresso.setText(text);
                    importDataAction.setEnabled(true);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private class ImportDataWorker extends SwingWorker<Void, Void> {

        private static final long SLEEP_TIME = 500;
        private int max;

        public ImportDataWorker(int max) {
            this.max = max;
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground() throws Exception {
            for (int i = 0; i < max; i++) {                
                setProgress(i);
                Thread.sleep(SLEEP_TIME);
            }
            return null;
        }

    }

    private static void createAndShowGui() {
        Minimo2 mainPanel = new Minimo2();

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Minimo2");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().add(mainPanel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> createAndShowGui());
    }
}
```